# Gravity form calculator interval

Tags: wordpress, calculator

I am going to make a calculator in Gravity Forms, but I dont know if its possible to do what I want.

It should be possible for people to calculate a price on a lawn.
So I have 1 input field to square meters and then I have 3 other fields with add ons to lawn.

But the prices in the 4 other fields, depents on how many square meters the customer types in the field for square meters.

So if the customer types in between 1-25 square meters, then field 1 cost = 2 USD field 2 cost = 6 USD field 3 cost = 7 USD

But if the customer then types in from 26-40, then field 1,2,3 should cost another price.
It that possible, does anybody no that.

Thank :)

Answer (score 1):

I will give you the idea on how to do this via Javascript. Am assuming that Gravity Form fields accepts `id` attributes. Let the `id` attribute of each fields be `in_square`, `field_1`, `field_2`, and `field_3`

So the fields might look like this:

```
<input type="text" id="in_square" />

<input type="text" id="field_1" />

<input type="text" id="field_2" />

<input type="text" id="field_3" />
```

Using Javascript, you could try something like this:

```
jQuery(function($){

  $('#in_square').on('change keyup', function(){
    var in_square = parseInt( $('#in_square').val() ),  // read the input
        field_1 = '',
        field_2 = '',
        field_3 = '';

    // conditions
    if( in_square >= 1 && in_square <= 25 )
    {
      field_1 = '2 USD';
      field_2 = '6 USD';
      field_3 = '7 USD';
    }
    else if( in_square >= 26 && in_square <= 40 )
    {
      field_1 = '3 USD';
      field_2 = '8 USD';
      field_3 = '10 USD';
    }
    //... and goes on..

    // assign the values back to the fields
    $('#field_1').val( field_1 );
    $('#field_2').val( field_2 );
    $('#field_3').val( field_3 );
  });
    
});
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpy58b49/

You can use the [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) to inject this Javascript file.

Answer (score 0):

The [Gravity Forms Conditional Pricing](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-conditional-pricing/) perk makes this super straightforward to setup. Here's an rough example of how this might be configured:

[image]